# Linq ".any" equivalent in HQL

Tags: java, linq, hibernate, nhibernate, hql

I have a NHibernate Linq query and I need to translate it to HQL:

```
var result = Conexion.Session.Query<Person>();
result = result.Where(p => p.addresses.Any(a => a.City.Name == "mycity"));
```

Returns the people who have at least one adress in the city "MyCity"

How I can translate the "any" clause to "HQL sintax"?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a small note - could be useful later. The LINQ statement creates EXISTS clause, which does not effect the root SELECT. That's how the HQL as shown with EXISTS will work the same way. JOIN on the other hand will effect the row count. That could lead to scenarios, when two address related to person contain Name == "mycity". And that will in that case lead to "non-pagable" resultset. Other words - SUBselect will later support paging later ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the HQL equivalent:

```
select p 
from Person p
join p.addresses a
join a.city c
where c.name = :cityName
```

The **any** is simply resolved by the one-to-many join where condition.

If there are multiple addresses within the same City, to remove Person entity duplicates, you need to use `distinct`:

```
select distinct p 
from Person p
join p.addresses a
join a.city c
where c.name = :cityName
```

or

```
select distinct p 
from Address a 
join fetch a.person p 
join a.city c 
where c.name = :cityName
```

Comment: Is that really the same? What happens if the person has two addresses in the same city? Will this generate duplicate persons (unlike the LINQ query)?

Comment: You can apply `distinct` to remove duplicates, if that's the case.

Comment: I might not be too acquainted with JPQL (i.e. not at all), but wouldn't you just intuitively prefer to somehow semi-join the path from person to city? I.e. using `IN` or `EXISTS`?

Comment: Will a second SELECT (when using EXISTS) perform better than a JOIN? I think it all depends on the database execution plan.

Comment: `EXISTS` will issue a second `SELECT` statement!? I will clearly shut up now and first improve my JPQL skills. Thanks for your info!

Comment: Am I missing something? EXISTS uses a second SELECT: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: Vlad! ;) Of course there is a second SELECT, syntax-wise. But this doesn't mean that a second SELECT is executed at the server side. Any sensible database will translate an `EXISTS` predicate into a semi-join, i.e. a join that aborts processing as soon as the predicate is met...

Comment: The query is clearly an exercise, I doubt there's a real business case where you have to select all persons from a whole City (e.g. New York has 8 million inhabitants).

Comment: Vlad, I'm shocked! Why wouldn't I want to search all my customers who live in NYC? I mean, e.g. to mail them about a special NYC-only promotion!? :)

Comment: If only it were about searching. The query wants to fetch the matching persons too. Now comes into play the JPA global fetch plan too. The JOIN optimization might not be the first place to start optimizing from.

Answer (score 4):

To replicate the SQL generated by:

```
var result = Conexion.Session.Query<Person>();
result = result.Where(p => p.addresses.Any(a => a.City.Name == "mycity"));
```

we have to do it like this:

```
var hql = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE EXISTS "
          + "(SELECT a FROM Address a "
          + "  LEFT JOIN a.City c "
          + "  WHERE p = a.Person " 
          + "    AND c.Name = 'mycity') ";
```

***mycity*** could be even parameter:

```
var hql = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE EXISTS "
          + "(SELECT a FROM Address a "
          + "  LEFT JOIN a.City c "
          + "  WHERE p = a.Person " 
          + "    AND c.Name = :mycity) ";

var result = Conexion.Session.CreateQuery(hql)
        .SetParameter("mycity", "...")
        .List<Person()
```

That will work, in case, that `Address` has a back reference to `Person`, because that is part of condition **`WHERE p = a.Person`**

In case, that mapping contains only way from Person to Address, hql must be like this:

```
var hql = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE EXISTS "
          + "(SELECT p2 FROM Person p2 "
          + "  LEFT JOIN p2.addresses a "
          + "  LEFT JOIN a.City c "
          + "  WHERE p = p2 " 
          + "    AND c.Name = :mycity) ";
```

That will work even if the referenc from address to person is missing